# Angular 2 error on loading less files

Tags: angular, systemjs

Im working on a Angular 2 Projekt with SystemJS and im using less for styling my components.

I started with the Quick Start Tutorial of angular 2 and changed to less  files.

systemjs.config.js

```
(function () {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            // ...
            'css': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-css',
            'less': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-less',
            'lesscss': 'npm:less'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            lesscss: {
                main: {
                    browser: './dist/less.min.js',
                    node: '@node/less'
                }
            },
            css: {
                main: 'css.js'
            },
            less: {
                main: 'less.js'
            }
        },
        meta: {
            '*.less': { loader: 'less' }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

I installed the less plugin and the files are loading but i get an error:

> Error: (SystemJS) Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.

login.component.ts

```
import { Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { Router }       from '@angular/router';

import { DwhService }   from '../../theme/services/dwh.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styles: [require('./login.component.less')]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    user: string = "";
    password: string = "";

    loginPattern:Object = {

    };

    loginData:Object = {};

    constructor(public dwhService:DwhService, public router: Router){

    }

    ngOnInit() : void {
        this.dwhService.json(this.loginPattern).toPromise().then(ret => {
            $.extend(true, this.loginData, ret);
        });
    }

    login():void{
        // ...
    }
}
```

I found a workaround but is it possible to set an loader for the less/css files?
I dont want to add String() to all *.less imports:

> styles: [String(require('./login.component.less'))]

Answer (score 0):

`SystemJS` should be able to load the relative link if you use `styleUrls`.

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.less']
})
```

Comment: systemjs have to use the less compiler